# How to select records where a child does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In rails I have 2 tables:

```
bans(ban_id, admin_id)
ban_reasons(ban_reason_id, ban_id, reason_id)
```

I want to find all the `bans` for a certain admin where there is no record in the `ban_reasons` table. How can I do this in Rails without looping through all the ban records and filtering out all the ones with `ban.ban_reasons.nil?` I want to do this (hopefully) using a single SQL statement.

I just need to do: (But I want to do it the "rails" way)

```
SELECT bans.* FROM bans WHERE admin_id=1234 AND 
                              ban_id NOT IN (SELECT ban_id FROM ban_reasons)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works great (only one request) but it's almost plain SQL:

```
bans = Ban.where("bans.id NOT IN (SELECT ban_id from ban_reason)")
```

You may also try the following, and let rails do part of the job:

```
bans = Ban.where("bans.id NOT IN (?)", BanReason.select(:ban_id).map(&:ban_id).uniq)
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the two? Does the second one result in more queries?

Comment: Yes, you get 1 more query with the second one… I think that the performance issue really depends of your DB size.

Comment: I guess if the aim is to use Rails whatever the cost then the suggestion works, but performance is going to suffer horribly for large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord only gets you to a point, everything after should be done by raw SQL. The good thing about AR is that it makes it pretty easy to do that kind of stuff.

However, since Rails 3, you can do almost everything with the AREL API, although raw SQL may or may not look more readable.

I'd go with raw SQL and here is another query you could try if yours doesn't perform well:

```
SELECT       b.* 
FROM         bans b
LEFT JOIN    ban_reason br on b.ban_id = br.ban_id
WHERE        br.ban_reason_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This is going to perform better on most db's than the other one above.  Many db have pretty poor IN performance (where they figure out sets).  This will have a certain performance hit as well do to searching for a null value on the join, but I still think it is likely better than the above.

Comment: Implementing it as a NOT EXISTS() would be a more natural syntax for this query I think, but I think you're right that SQL is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem (which I'm author of):

```
Ban.where(admin_id: 123).where_not_exists(:ban_reasons)
```